# Make ajax call by pack of 2,3,4

Tags: javascript, ajax, async-await

Hello !

I am a student and for an internship I have to develop a javascript client for an  rest api. Currently I make my Ajax calls one by one thanks to "async and await" but the data that I have to load are very voluminous so I would like to make my ajax calls by pack of 2 or 3 to make it faster. I am a beginner in javascript and I do not see a simple way to do that, if you have any advice it would be cool!

thanks in advance :)

Comment: As I said nothing that is interesting because I do not see a way to do that easily

Comment: Done any research yet? Look into [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: I'm looking for 2 hours, that's why I asked the question, but your link seems to meet what I'm looking for, I'll look at it in detail, thank you for your help anyway!

Answer (score 1):

```js
// this will resolve in under 200ms to simulate an ajax request
const fakeRequest = data =>
  new Promise(res =>
    setTimeout(res, Math.floor(Math.random() * 200), data))

async function main() {
  // resolve all promises firing them off at the same time
  const result = await Promise.all([
      // multiple promises
      fakeRequest({ id: 1 }),
      fakeRequest({ id: 2 }),
      fakeRequest({ id: 3 })
    ])
    // convert the results into an object
    .then(([a, b, c]) => ({ a, b, c }))
  
  console.log(result)
}
// run your async function
main()
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/KyQQmL.js"></script>
```